# Ruby: Print un-printable data string

Tags: ruby, string, printing, hex

If I have a variable, x, that will sometime be a normal printable string, and sometimes be some random hex data (including unprintable chars), how can I reliably print that will space padding? ex:

```
def print(x)
  puts("%-15s" % x) 
end

x = "test"
print(x) 
x = Array.new(256) { rand(256) }.pack('c*')
print(x)
```

Comment: `that will sometime be a ...`, `print that will space padding` ? typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print(x)
  puts "%-15s" % [x.inspect]
end
```

And if you want to get rid of the `"..."`:

```
puts "%-15s" % [x.inspect[1..-2]]
```

Comment: Although you probably know this, note that `String#%` does not require the argument to be an array if only one item is being passed, i.e. `puts "%-15s" % x.inspect`